# Android Studio - Error: ADB not responding on Linux

Tags: android, adb, android-studio

I have been using Android Studio on **Linux** Mint since quite some time now.
Recently I have upgraded Android Studio to 0.2.6.
Since then I am having this strange error some times

> ADB not responding. You can wait more, or kill "adb" process manually and click 'Restart'
>   Errors from ADB:
>   ddms: Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger

And my manifest fails to recognize my resources.And I get these errors

> [debug] /tmp/android_manifest_copy930577311558645040tmp/AndroidManifest.xml:12: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher').

I have been getting every now and then, restarting my computer fixes them. But it is very disturbing in the middle of development. 
Can any body suggest a permanent solution to this??
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Now even restarting the computer hasn't fixed it.

Comment: your problem seemed like the following:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246983/adb-not-responding-android-studio