# ADB Not Responding - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intellij-idea, android-studio

Don't mark this as a duplicate.  Let me explain what's wrong and tell you what I've done.  So here's my problem.  When I open Android Studio, it gives me an error like so:

[image: TCP/IP]

So then I went to my windows firewall settings.  Here is what I have:

[image: Windows Firewall]

As you can see, Firewall is off.  Then, I went to my antivirus security program and turned the settings off there:

[image: Norton Firewall]

As you can see here too, I disabled Smart Firewall.  Then, I opened Android Studio again.  I got the same error here too.

[image: TCP/IP]

I pressed the OK button and moved on.  Then, Android Studio loaded up and everything.  After that, ADB started loading.  This is where the real error occurs.

[image: ADB Error]

I have also tried it with Eclipse, but it also says ADB not responding.  For the past month or so, Android Studio has been working fine.  I have never gotten these error or warning messages with Android Studio before, so this is rather new to me.

Here is what I have tried:

- In cmd, `adb kill-server` then I pressed the restart button on the ADB not responding message
- Restarting computer
- Turning USB Debugging on and off on my Nexus 5

So, I really can't find a solution to this.  Any help regarding this problem would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: try to run `adb devices` in command prompt inside folder sdk/platform tools.

Comment: @pyus13 It works through command prompt, but it doesn't through the IDE.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it just gets into a mess. Close your ide then Go to processes and terminate all adb processes.

Then when you open up android studio it should kick off adb again fresh (or you could run something like 'adb devices' from command prompt before opening the ide if you're worried it gets in to a bad state while the ide is waiting for it to initialize)

If none of that works you could also reboot your device. I've very rarely found it necessary, but it has helped me in the past

Comment: For some reason, this is not solving the problem.  But thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Kill processes bas_deamon & bas_helper]

Kill processes bas_deamon & bas_helper Then press restart for ADB and it will work.... this what I do in WIndows 7 when I face this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to make sure your phone is unplugged.  When it is plugged in, I have noticed this happening and the solution for me (which may be Mac specific) is to unplug my phone from the computer.

Comment: It Worked for me, close IDE, kill adb.exe, unplug the phone and start IDE

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error messages, but a different problem.
Port 5037 was not in use, but still adb couldn't start.

So after hours of trying I finally realized, that it was an installed VPN-client (Checkpoint Endpoint Security). Even though there was no connection (and I even killed the process) the connection didn't work. After uninstalling everything worked like a charm.

Maybe it helps someone who reads this question, because everywhere else you just read about the blocking port. And in addition, while the client was installed some other TCP-based Frameworks and even Windows-Remotedesktop stopped working too.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. I solve it by terminating all process that is using port "5037" which is, by default, the port used by adb.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I figured out the problem months ago and I realized that adware was plaguing my computer.  I removed the adware and everything began working normally again.

Answer (score 0):

Sir,
Actually Sometimes our parent control software interfere with it.  but after turning off its real time protection , we got this error. so basically you need to check the whether we are using 32 bit Android Studio or 64 bit. just try to av same bit operating system as of Android Studio , u ll get this error removed after that. :)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows: add a system variable as following and then restart your Computer then try again - it will be OK

```
ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT
10501
```

[image: add System Variable]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Mac OS X. After some research I've found a bad entry in my `/etc/hosts` file for my localhost (`192.168.99.100 localhost`).

I removed the bad line and left the line `127.0.0.1 localhost` for ipv4 and some entries for ipv6 in.

After a reboot the Android Studio was able to communicate with adb and found my connected Android device again.